# Серверная часть для android-приложения на Java?

Tags: java, android, клиент-сервер, kotlin

Добрый день, уважаемые разработчики. Столкнулся с задачей выбора способа реализации серверной части для android-приложения. Суть: пишется небольшое приложения ради обучения. Приложение позволяет регистрироваться пользователям и редактировать информацию о книгах (книжная библиотека с CRUD функционалом). Взаимодействие будет реализовано на HTTP. В целях изучения реализации взаимодействия клиент-сервер имеется желание для сервера выбрать java, но поскольку опыта нет, интересует также Ваше мнение по этому вопросу. Возможно ли реализовать сервер именно на java с сервлетами или придётся писать на Kotlin?

Comment: возможно на чем угодно его реализовать, это ни на что не повлияет. но если не собираетесь работать в enterprise, то лучше бы реализовали его на php, python, ruby. рекомендую php или python

Comment: А если я хочу работать в Enterprise, но в компании, занимающейся разработкой не мобильных приложений? Например в сфере телекоммуникаций? @koshkashoshka

Comment: в конкретной компании? там и узнавайте. если это enterprise, то либо asp.net, либо java на серверах... мобильное приложение здесь ни при чем вообще, еще раз, протокол HTTP независим от языка и платформы

Comment: А клиент серверное приложение пишется одним проектом, или отдельным клиент и отдельным сервер? Сколько репозиториев на гитхабе нужно создать под такое? @koshkashoshka

Comment: @lexx.step можно и одним, если на модули разбить и переиспользовать часть модулей и на клиенте, и на сервере. Не принципиально.

Comment: @lexx.step Неважно. Еще раз повторяю, протокол HTTP абстрагирован от всей этой ерунды. И почему бы самому тему не изучить в процессе? А по репозиториям, можно и минус 1

Answer (score 1):

Клиент - это одна часть (отображает данные)

Сервер - это другая часть (начитка данных из бд или других мест)

Клиентом может быть любое приложение, взаимодействующее с сервером через интернет (android приложение, какой-либо сайт или десктопное приложение)
Сервер никак не зависит от клиента, т.к. он лишь отвечает на запросы от клиента и т.к. протокол для всех одинаковый, то и общаться с ним могут различные приложения.

В качестве сервера можно реализовать REST или SOAP сервис. В кратце REST возвращает в качестве ответа json, а soap сервис в качестве ответа возвращает xml (знаю, что по soap можно сгенерировать код клиента на java).

Если хочется реализовать сервис на java, то можно его писать и на kotlin и на groovy, т.к. они совместимы с java (но миксовать все 3 сразу не желательно).

Вот есть пример rest сервиса на kotlin (вероятно можно найти более современные примеры) - https://auth0.com/blog/developing-restful-apis-with-kotlin/

Теперь про клиента.
На андроид можно использовать библиотеку retrofit и okhttp3 для запросов к REST сервису и библиотеку rxjava для того, чтобы данные можно было грузить в отдельном потоке не тормозя при этом UI (таким образом потом UI продолжает исполнение и как только данные загрузятся, они отобразятся).

Ниже представлен пример подключения к rest на android+kotlin

```
val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(CONNECT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build()
val adapter = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://localhost")
            .client(client)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(Gson()))
            .build()

authRepo = AuthRepository(adapter.create(
                AuthDataSource::class.java))


interface AuthDataSource {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("login/login")
    fun authenticate(@FieldMap params: Map<String, String>): Observable<User>

}

abstract class Repository {
    protected fun <T> applySchedulers(): Observable.Transformer<T, T> {
        return Observable.Transformer<T, T> { observable -> observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) }
    }
}

class AuthRepository(private val authDataSource: AuthDataSource) : Repository() {

    fun authenticate(login: String, password: String): Observable<User> {
        return authDataSource
                .authenticate(
                        mapOf(
                                "phone" to login,
                                "password" to password
                        )
                )
                .compose(this.applySchedulers<User>())
    }
```